# How to stop texcount from counting \begin{comment}...\end{comment}

Tags: texcount

Is there a way to stop `texcount` from counting words in `\begin{comment}...\end{comment}` blocks? It seems to skip only comments starting with `%`

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
%TC:group comment 0 0
```

somewhere near the top of your file.
See http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#newgroup.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%TC:group comment 0 0
\begin{document}
one
\begin{comment}
  two three four five six seven eight
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

---

```
$ texcount tc.tex
File: tc.tex
Encoding: ascii
Words in text: 1
Words in headers: 0
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 0
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 0
Number of math displayed: 0
```

Comment: Just to elaborate... Starting with version 3 of TeXcount, you can use named parsing rules instead of the numerical codes, as well as _envir_ as an alias of _group_: e.g. the line _%TC:envir comment [] ignore_ is equivalent to _%TC:group comment 0 0_ where the arguments indicate the number of arguments taken (_[]_ = _0_ = none) and their rules, and the rule for parsing the environment (_ignore_ = _0_).